# How to check if a number is a concatenation of 1, 14 or 144

Tags: python

I've managed to get the code to check whether or not it's a concatenation of 1, 14, or 144 but the main problem here is that when I print numbers like 144441 it returns "YES" when it should give a "NO."

This problem occurs as long as there are at least 3 fours sandwiched between 2 ones (i.e. 14441, 14444444444441, 1444441)

```
def magic_num(N):
    magic = N

    while magic in range(1,1000000001):
        if (magic % 1000 == 144):
            magic /= 1000
        elif (magic % 100 == 14):
            magic /= 100
        elif (magic % 10 == 1):
            magic /= 10
        else:
            return"NO"

    return "YES"

N = int(input("Enter an integer between 1 and 10^9: "))
print(magic_num(N));
```

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? You should be doing integer division and then checking whether `magic == 0`. You almost certainly don't need to check `while magic in range(1,1000000001)`

Comment: `magic` is floating point after the first iteration, and so is not `in range(1, 100000001)`. Replace `/` with `//` and use `magic >= 1` instead of the range check.

Comment: Because division in Python 3+ produces a float, potentially with stuff after the decimal. `magic = 144` and then `magic /= 1000` will set `magic` to `0.144` not `0` like you seem to expect. Use [floor division](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-floor-division) instead `magic //= 1000` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

I think for your case you just need to check that your number only contains `1`s and `4`s, that it starts with a `1` and that you don't have three or more `4`'s in a row:

```py
def is_concatenation(n):
    """Returns True if n is a concatenation of 1, 14 and 144"""
    n = str(n)
    return set(n) <= {"1", "4"} and n.startswith("1") and "444" not in n
```

Answer (score 2):

I really suggest using RegEx (Regular Expression) to handle this issue. You can do that simply like so:

```
import re

regex = r"^(1+4{,2})+$"
def is_concatenation(N):
    return re.match(regex, str(N)) is not None
```

Let's test this function over some test-cases:

```
>>> is_concatentaion(1)
True
>>> is_concatentaion(14)
True
>>> is_concatentaion(144)
True
>>> is_concatentaion(1444)
False
>>> is_concatentaion(14414)
True
>>> is_concatentaion(14414111)
True
>>> is_concatentaion(144414111)
False
>>> is_concatentaion(144441)
False
>>> is_concatentaion(14444444444441)
False
>>> is_concatentaion(1444441)
False
```

Comment: Just an observation: the performance of this solution seems to be more variable on the content of the string than the others.  For example, the string "111141141111111114114114411114411441411414111111111444141441411441" takes the better part of a *minute* to process where as the *longer* string "14111114144411411111414111114141411111441114111441111144144114111144144" takes a fraction of a *second*.  The solution of @Boris, for example, only takes a fraction of a second on *both*.

Answer (score 2):

I like the pattern match answer from @Anwarvic. However if you want make your approach work instead of converting it to a string, try this:

```
def magic_num(magic):

    while magic:
        if (magic % 1000 == 144):
            magic //= 1000
        elif (magic % 100 == 14):
            magic //= 100
        elif (magic % 10 == 1):
            magic //= 10
        else:
            return"NO"

    return "YES"

N = int(input("Enter an integer "))
print(magic_num(N))
```

You should be doing integer division. Also you just need to check that the result is not 0 as the loop terminator. As a result of that change you do not have to limit the size of the number input either.

You can directly operate on the number parameter passed in. In this context it is only changing the value passed and NOT changing the callers copy of the number passed in, so this is safe to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```py
from re import findall, search

def magic_num(n):
    n = str(n)
    
    if search("[^14]", n) or any(len(s) > 2 for s in findall("4+", n)):
        return "NO"
    return "YES"
```

Comment: This fails on strings like: "111", "1111", "1114", "11141", "111144", etc. that seem like they should succeed based on the OP's explanation of the rules.

Comment: The solution has been adjusted accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way:

```
n = [1, 14, 144]

def magic_num(N):
    n.sort(reverse=True) # Sort the list from greatest to least
    for number in n:
        if str(number) in N:
            while N != N.replace(str(number),'_',1):
                N = N.replace(str(number),'_',1)
    if N.replace('_','') == '':
        return 'YES'
    return 'NO'

N = input("Enter an integer: ")
print(magic_num(N))
```

This program will not work if the list isn't sorted from greatest to least.

The reason: Lets say our integer is `14414`.

When the program iterates through the list,

if it sees a `1` first, it will replace the first `1` in `14414`,

before the program notices the `144` that's supposed to be replaced,

leaving the program with `4414`, and obviously, it will return `'NO'`.

Comment: This fails on strings like: "11", "111", "1414", "1141", "1114", etc. that seem like they should succeed based on the OP's explanation of the rules.

Comment: This succeeds on strings like: "11444", "111444", etc. that seem like they should fail based on the OP's explanation of the rules.

Comment: @cdlane Thanks for the notification. I corrected it.

Comment: Looks good!  But consider getting rid of that debugging `print(N)` statement...